# sketch solutions of nonlinear differential equations system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the task to sketch the solution of
$$\begin{pmatrix} \dot x\\
\dot y
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
y\\
-V'(x)
\end{pmatrix},$$
where $V$ is a polynomial with $\lim\limits_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}V(x)= \infty$, two strict local minima $x_0<x_2$ and one strict local maxima $x_1 \in (x_0,x_2)$, where $V(x_2)< V(x_0)$.
Does anyone  know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This system has very particular form: you can rewrite it as $\ddot{x} = -V^\prime(x)$. Physicists instantly see this as a 1D particle subject to some conservative force with potential $V(x)$. The most important pecularity of such system is that it has energy conservation law: the quantity $\dfrac{\dot{x}^2(t)}{2} + V(x(t))$ which is full mechanical energy in this case is constant along any trajectory, i.e. $$\dfrac{\dot{x}^2(t)}{2} + V(x(t)) = \dfrac{\dot{x}^2(0)}{2} + V(x(0)).$$ Conservation of energy in such systems is a kind of inspiration for concept of "first integral". Just check that $\dfrac{y^2}{2} + V(x)$ doesn't change in time when you plug solution of ODE into it. This leads to one very useful observation: knowing how integral curves look like is the same as knowing how level sets of $\dfrac{y^2}{2} + V(x)$ look like. That's all you really need: just sketch the level sets of this function using remarks from the statement of your problem.